# How to use WS-Security with EJB3?

Tags: ejb-3.0, ws-security

For one of our projects, I should be able to call a webservice that uses WS-Security, i.e. the SOAP request should be signed with an X.509 certificate. I've been doing some tests to call the webservice through the use of the WebServiceRef annotation and I'm able to call the webservice without WS-Security.

So my question is: how can I activate and/or configure WS-Security when using the WebServiceRef annotation ?

Regards, Stefan Lecho.

Answer (score 1):

If it still relevant, have a look at [WSIT](https://wsit.dev.java.net/), and in particular, its WS-Security implementation described [here](https://xwss.dev.java.net/overview.html). Basically you just have to use @WebServiceRef as you usually do, provide a wsit-client.xml, and specify the proper <Policy> node.

You might find these useful:

- [Implementing WS-Security with public key certificates for Metro-based web services](http://www.jroller.com/gmazza/entry/implementing_ws_security_with_pki)
- [Configuring Keystores and Truststores](http://java.sun.com/webservices/reference/tutorials/wsit/doc/WSIT_Security6.html)